# Which errors can throw Ionic Secure Storage?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ionic3, storage, ionic-native

I want to control the possible errors that the Ionic Native plugin [Secure Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage/) (based on [Cordova Secure Storage Plugin](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage)) can throw when an error occurs while creating the storage namespace (`create()`) but I can not find any info about anywhere.

The only error I had found is one that throws an string saying "**Error: Device is not secure**" but is it the only one?? How can I be sure if the only problem is that the device does not has any pin or similar? is that **THE ONLY** error that can happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be other errors as well.

Below is a list of errors that can occur on **Android device**:

> MSG_NOT_SUPPORTED = "API 19 (Android 4.4 KitKat) is required. This
>   device is running API " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
>
> MSG_DEVICE_NOT_SECURE = "Device is not secure";

Errors caught during exception handling:

> FAILED_TO_INIT = "Init failed :" + error
>
> RSA_AES_ENCRYPTION_FAILED = "Encrypt (RSA/AES) failed :" + error
>
> RSA_AES_DECRYPTION_FAILED = "Decrypt (RSA/AES) failed :" + error
>
> RSA_DECRYPTION_FAILED = "Decrypt (RSA) failed :" + error
>
> RSA_ENCRYPTION_FAILED = "Encrypt (RSA) failed :" + error

Check [here](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage/blob/master/src/android/SecureStorage.java) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this. I do not understand why the plugin sends the error as string and not an object with some kind of `error.type`.

Comment: @distante it depends upon the coding style they are following but what you are suggesting is a better coding approach.